# NSInternalInconsistencyException - Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I am getting following exception:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/57C8544B-05F6-445D-80A9-FAC9672F278B/MyApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'MyNibName''
```

I tried number of solutions suggested in stackoverflow's similar questions, but still getting this issue.

This issue is with particular xib file which loads address book.

This occurs only on iPhone and not on iPad and simulator.

I also tried deleting the existing xib file and creating a new one but didnt work out.

```
With few attempts of testing, I found that the file works fine for certain number of attempts and then starts giving above error only on iPhone.
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have different targets for iPhone / iPad ?

Comment: Ugh… what a pain. I wonder if there is any more information about the exception. Have you set an exception breakpoint to trap the error? There should be more information available about what's happening. You could also wrap it in a @try/@catch block and set a breakpoint in the catch block.

Comment: No same target for ipad and iphone. But for iPad it works very well

Comment: If I rename or create xib file, for the first time it works very well for iPhone. But for next attempt, it crashes at [self.view addSubview:myXib.view];

Comment: Any chance to see the view controller initialization ?

Comment: AddressBookContactsViewController *abc ;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
                    
abc = [[AddressBookContactsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddressBookContactsViewControlleriPhone" bundle:nil ];
                
                }else {
                    
                    abc = [[AddressBookContactsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddressBookContactsViewController_iPad" bundle:nil ];
                
                
                }
                
                [self.view addSubview:abc.view];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after long debugging and testing, I found the issue. The issue was NOT with NIB file, but it was with two nsmutablearrays that I had declared and was populating but not using them. I removed them and then it worked. This was bit strange for me.